# Nginx cuts off part of the response from php-fpm

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx

Ubuntu 16.04. Installed Yandex Odyssey 1.0rc1. I launched it and when I immediately received a response from php, nginx began to cut off the response from php. We checked on the php side, php has no less data and sends all the data. Having decided that the problem was in Yandex Odyssey, I stopped and launched pgbouncer. The same result is truncated data by 2-3 bytes. The Yandex Odyssey was assembled on the continent. Why does nginx truncate the response?

In the PHP code we calculate the length of the content ourselves. If you remove it, everything works fine. Before this there was no error and everything worked with the content-length set in the code. content length required. There are rights to the folders (checked for both nginx and php). I reinstalled both nginx and php-fpm, nothing helped.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#thread_pool first threads=128 max_queue=0;
#thread_pool second threads=64;


#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#    server {
#        listen       80;
#        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

#        location / {
#            root   html;
#            index  index.html index.htm;
#        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
#        location = /50x.html {
#            root   html;
#        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
        include conf.d/*.conf;
#    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

    include sites-enabled/*.conf;
    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: Hello Vladimir, and welcome to SO. Do you mind sharing your nginx configuration ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add nginx.conf.